# How to show Trello in an iFrame

Tags: iframe, trello

I am putting together a dashboard to show project progress.

It's a dead simple page - basically divided into quarters, with an iframe in each quarter.

We use Trello for our KanBan board and I want to embed it in this dashboard - unfortunately I get the following message:

> **This content cannot be displayed in a frame**
>
> To help protect the security of information you enter into this website,  the publisher of this content does not allow it to be
>   displayed in a frame.

Looking around, they for this to prevent ClickJacker attacks, but wonder if there is a way round it.

My plan B is to write a c# app that will open 4 browsers and resized them all to fit into quarters of the screen, but this is obviously a lot more work!

Comment: You can iframe a static version of your board - see http://jsfiddle.net/danlec/hmQJP/ - but as you mentioned, we don't allow iframing of the live version to avoid clickjacking.  Does the static version help?  If so, I'll write up a more thorough answer about how to do it.

Comment: That would be useful. I don't need instant update, so could refresh hourly or something. Many thanks!

Comment: Oh!  I should probably note that we only allow public boards to be served in this way.  If you can't make the relevant board public, this won't work for you.

Comment: Thanks @AaronDufour, the html preview was what I needed. Ben, if you didn't already find a solution, you might want to try http://www.stefandidak.com/windows-layout-manager/

Answer (score 7):

Here [is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danlec/hmQJP/) that shows code to iframe embed a trello board:

```
<iframe src="https://trello.com/c/OKVduwHL.html" frameBorder="0" width="340" height="220"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. This will actually work for a simple use case I have. However, it should be notes this only works for Public boards.